# Ember.js - ember-pikaday not allowing preset date

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datepicker

I am trying to create a datepicker in ember.js using the `ember-pikaday` addon. The datepicker should have a date in it when it is displayed. So, I added the following code to my template:

```
{{pikaday-input value=rental.date format="MMMM Do YYYY" yearRange="2016" useUtc=true}}
```

However, even though I specify the value as `rental.date`, the input is blank. I know that the value of `rental.date` is not null because when I set the placeholder to `rental.date`, the placeholder's date is correct.

Comment: What is the format for `rental.date`?  Pikaday expects a JS date object. Try a new variable: `parsedDate = new Date(rental.date)` and pass that as the value.

Comment: @sbatson5 `rental.date` is a momentjs object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your case is due to the fact that you are passing a momentjs object to ember-pikaday directly. Instead of passing the momentjs object directly just create a computed property called as follows on your owner component:

```
  rentalDate:Ember.computed('rental.date', function() {
      return this.get('rental.date').toDate();
  }),
```

and perform binding to rentalDate. ember-pikaday does not handle momentjs object passed in by itself, just extract the actual javascript date object via toDate() as shown in code snippet above. Just for clarification you can also pass formatted string to ember-pikaday such as "25/05/2016", "2016.05.25", etc. It will also handle such string values properly.